# If else statement with preg_match not working

Tags: php, regex

I am checking the login and password from my form. It shouldn't contain any special chars.
The commented `return var_dump` shows me the login and password values properly.
Unfortunately none of the `if` and `else` are not returned at all.
Why does that happen?

```
$usernCheck = $_POST['usern'];
$passCheck = $_POST['passn'];
// return var_dump($usernCheck.$passCheck);

if( (preg_match("!@#$%^&*()_+-=,./<>?;':\"{}[]", $usernCheck) !== false) 
    OR (preg_match("!@#$%^&*()_+-=,./<>?;':\"{}[]", $passCheck) !== false) ){
    return "Found special chars.";
} else {
    return "Not found special chars.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match` only returns `false` if an error occurred. It will return `0` if the pattern doesn't match, so using `!== false` is probably not a good comparison, because while `0 == false` (equality), `0 !== false` (identity).

Without fully reviewing your regexes, I would suggest just letting the return value of `preg_match` evaluate as boolean. If a match is found, it will return `1`, which will evaluate as true.

```
if( preg_match($pattern, $usernCheck) || preg_match($pattern, $passCheck) {
    return "Found special chars.";
} else {
    return "Not found special chars.";
}
```

After reviewing your regex a bit, it looks like many of the characters there have meaning in regex and need to be escaped, and the set of characters should be enclosed in `[]` to match *any* character in the list rather than *all* of them. Something like:

```
'[!@#\$%\^\&\*\(\)_\+-=,\.\/<>\?;\':\"{}\[\]]'
```

But there may be other special characters. It may be better to specify which characters *are* allowed instead of blacklisting specific ones.